# I want to day by day stock details from database query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to simple query that give me stock day by day details.

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT 
    TRNDATE, I_NAME, 
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS OPENING, SUM(PURCHASE) AS PURCHASE,
    SUM(SALE) AS SALE, SUM(AMOUNT) + SUM(PURCHASE) - SUM(SALE) AS STOCK
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         TRNDATE, I_NAME, AMOUNT AS OPENING, 0 AS PURCHASE,
         0 AS SALE, 0 AS STOCK 
     FROM DBO.ITEMMAST 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         TRNDATE, I_NAME, 0 AS OPENING, AMOUNT AS PURCHASE,
         0 AS SALE, 0 AS STOCK 
     FROM DBO.PURCHASE 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         TRNDATE, I_NAME, 0 AS OPENING, 0 AS PURCHASE,
         AMOUNT AS SALE,0 AS STOCK 
     FROM DBO.SALE) MAIN 
GROUP BY 
    TRNDATE, I_NAME
```

Output is

| Item | Date | opening | Purchase | Sale | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gold | 10/01/2022 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Gold | 11/01/2022 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| Gold | 12/01/2022 | 0 | 0 | 2 | -2 |

The result returns only same line summary

I want to be like this

| Item | Date | opening | Purchase | Sale | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gold | 10/01/2022 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| Gold | 11/01/2022 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 13 |
| Gold | 12/01/2022 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 11 |

I need to get line by line summary.

Comment: Seems like you want a cumulative `SUM` for your last column, *not* an overall aggregate.

Comment: yes i need sum of last column stock, how can i get **cumulative SUM** ?

Comment: Almost surely this needs an ORDER BY clause as well. A resultset containing a cumulative sum is useless if the rows are not sorted in the proper order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* this is what you are after, however, it is impossible to test. What you want is a cumulative `SUM`, which is the one at the end with the `OVER` clause. As a result you need to use another derived table.

I prefer to use CTEs over subqueries, as they are reusable through the query, so I change your query to use those and end up with the following:

```sql
WITH Items AS(
    SELECT TRNDATE,
             I_NAME,
             AMOUNT AS OPENING,
             0 AS PURCHASE,
             0 AS SALE,
             0 AS STOCK
      FROM dbo.ITEMMAST
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TRNDATE,
             I_NAME,
             0 AS OPENING,
             AMOUNT AS PURCHASE,
             0 AS SALE,
             0 AS STOCK
      FROM dbo.PURCHASE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TRNDATE,
             I_NAME,
             0 AS OPENING,
             0 AS PURCHASE,
             AMOUNT AS SALE,
             0 AS STOCK
      FROM dbo.SALE),
Aggregrates AS(
    SELECT TRNDATE,
           I_NAME,
           SUM(OPENING) AS OPENING, --Note you had SUM(AMOUNT) in your original attempt
           SUM(PURCHASE) AS PURCHASE,
           SUM(SALE) AS SALE
    FROM Items
    GROUP BY TRNDATE,
             I_NAME)
SELECT TRNDATE,
       I_NAME,
       OPENING, 
       PURCHASE,
       SALE,
       SUM(OPENING + PURCHASE - SALE) OVER (PARTITION BY I_NAME ORDER BY TRNDATE
                                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS STOCK
FROM Aggregrates;
```